# ffmpeg - copy attached-fonts without encode/remux

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a mkv file with audio, video and subtitles. It also has a lot (~50) fonts (idk why).
The size and all is fine, but I want to make the one subtitle stream, default.

The problem is, when I use "-c copy", it loses all fonts. I know that I can keep everything with "-map 0", but this encodes all streams and goes from 70k fps (-c copy) down to only 20 fps -> takes a very long time.

This is the command I used:

```
$ ffmpeg -i 1.mkv -c copy -disposition:s:0 default 2.mkv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation regarding automatic [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection):

> Data or attachment streams are not automatically selected and can only be included using `-map`.

Example to include **all** streams:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mkv -map 0 -c copy -disposition:s:0 default 2.mkv
```

See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).

Comment: For some reason I thought you cant use both flags at once. Well there goes a full day of remuxing. Thank you very much, this will save me a lot of time in the future!